# Using ELMAH Log Exceptions in a single XML file in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, elmah

ELMAH has some really magical features but is there any way to log all exceptions in a single XML file rather then generating new files for every single exception that would be caught or generated over and over again by the user.

Kind Regards
Fahad

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. However, elmah is open source so you can change it to your requirements.